How can I use the slugs in directus?
Creating articles on cms directus (version 11.3.5) that I want to use for a blog.
I've found the documentation about creating slugs automatically and the discussions on github
I've used it on the title field on my articles, with the following code :
module.exports = async function (data) {
    // Index data to get the string you want to slugify
    // Assign it to the "text" var below.
    const text = data.$trigger.payload.title;

    const slug = text
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '')
        .replace(/[\s_-]+/g, '-')
        .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');

    return { 
        ...data.$trigger.payload, slug
    }
};


I've used it on the scope item.create and item.update, on my articles_translations table which holds the translated data of each article.
I've created the flow as precised and got no errors. I don't understand now how I can check it worked ? In which field will it be stored ?

I had to create a slug field on the table article_translation for it to work.
I've used this snippet instead :
const slugify = text =>
  text
    .toString()
    .normalize('NFD')
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '')
    .replace(/--+/g, '-');

module.exports = async function(data) {
    // if title not passed
    if (data.$trigger.payload.title === undefined) return data.$trigger.payload;
    // if user entered slug themselves...
    if (data.$trigger.payload.slug !== undefined) return data.$trigger.payload;
    /// generate slug
    const slug = slugify(data.$trigger.payload.title);
    return {...data.$trigger.payload, slug};
}

from this website.
To create the slug on update, you have to update the title - else it's not part of the payload when updating. If you forget it, with this snippet it won't crash (it does with the first one on update)
so:

create the slug field (just a regular input field) for it to be filled automatically with the script
use the script in the flows as stated here

